# Usb stick not mounted/detected

Tags: usb, hard-drive, 18.04

On my desktop I always have plugged in two usb ports my two external hard drives. I'm having a 16GB Kingstone usb stick which I try to plug to another free usb port but can't detect it. I have run the `fdisk -l` and outputs this

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 21 MiB, 22003712 bytes, 42976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 140 MiB, 146841600 bytes, 286800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 33 MiB, 34635776 bytes, 67648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 21.6 MiB, 22609920 bytes, 44160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 102.9 MiB, 107835392 bytes, 210616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 86.6 MiB, 90759168 bytes, 177264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 3.7 MiB, 3813376 bytes, 7448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 140 MiB, 146841600 bytes, 286800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4241DC6E-99EB-4B11-A37D-6A59E99572D4

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 454948863 453898240 216.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  454948864 488396799  33447936    16G Linux swap




Disk /dev/loop8: 180.5 MiB, 189272064 bytes, 369672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 12.2 MiB, 12804096 bytes, 25008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 13 MiB, 13594624 bytes, 26552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 1.6 MiB, 1691648 bytes, 3304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 2.3 MiB, 2428928 bytes, 4744 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 146.2 MiB, 153284608 bytes, 299384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop14: 3.3 MiB, 3411968 bytes, 6664 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8a9b287f

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 976768064 976766017 465.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdc: 930.9 GiB, 999501594624 bytes, 1952151552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0002ae3f

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 1952151551 1952149504 930.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Also the output of `lsblk` is

```
loop9    7:9    0  12.2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/69
loop10   7:10   0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/86
loop11   7:11   0   1.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/154
loop12   7:12   0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/167
loop13   7:13   0 146.2M  1 loop /snap/skype/30
loop14   7:14   0   3.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0 216.4G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0    16G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part /media/lykos/INTENSO // one of my external hard drives
sdc      8:32   0 930.9G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 930.9G  0 part /media/lykos/My Book // one of my external hard drives
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sr1     11:1    1   668M  0 rom
```

Here's also what I get from gparted
[image]

Also on `media` folder I can only see the 2 external hard drives and not the usb stick. Any help please?

Comment: I copied the wrong output from terminal before :) Did an update

Comment: On my laptop (windows) works fine

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have errors on the USB drive's filesystem. If you can get to a state where the device (here `/dev/sdd`) has been created, then, as it is not mounted, run `e2fsck` on it to automatically fix any errors, e.g.

```
sudo e2fsck -y /dev/sdd
```

Look at the `e2fsck` man page for description and options.  And if `e2fsck` didn't work check all the physical connections, Inc USB cable and any other parts in the chain, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Is your USB stick detected by your system? When you connect/disconnect the stick you should see a message in the kernel log. You can use the **dmesg** command to see what happens.
Check for lines including the word usb.

Comment: This is the last entry `[ 4612.182420] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 6248808 \n
[ 4612.288125] blk_partition_remap: fail for partition 1`

Answer (score 0):

It might help, if you unmount and after that unplug the other two USB drives, or even reboot the system and plug you Kingston USB stick into one of the USB ports, that you know are working.

The following link may help you analyze the problem.

[Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

> - Reboot the computer and try again.
> - Disconnect other USB devices. and try again. Sometimes USB devices can disturb the function for each other.
> - Try other USB ports, and/or other card adapters.
>
> ---
>
> - Try another computer.
> - Try another operating system (Windows, MacOS) in another computer. *You know that it works in Windows.*

So maybe there is

- a problem with the USB port
- confusion because of the other two USB drives or maybe some other USB device, that is connected.
- lacking compatibility between the USB stick and your computer's USB system (hardware or software problem).